# How should I use LINQ with UnitOfWork

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to get some data

```
 var res = ToBllEntity(from person in UnitOfWork.Person where person.id == id select person);
```

But it is incorect. UnitOfWork.Person has error 'Where is not found'. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Add the Linq namespace?

Add to the top of your file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: I have done it in a few classes, suck as:
Service class(this code in tis class), Repository class, IUnit OfWork interface and UnitOfWork class. It is not work

Comment: It is work for example, but I want to use not methods, i need just linq
______________________
return ToBllEntity(UnitOfWork.RankingOfFriend.GetAll().Where(s => s.Id == id));

Comment: More detail discriotion of error. ___________Could not find an implementation of the query template for the source type "IGenericRepository <>". "Where" not found.